# What options do I have if I am interested in Mathematics, specifically Statistics, Probability and Combinotorics

Tags: job-search, applications, careers

I have an interest in studying Math topics involving calculus, statistics and probability (Basically I love Maths but am not a big fan of proofs related work, so I don't want to consider being a researcher or mathematician). I am a CS major with Applied Mathematics as part of my degree. I am about to enter my final year and I have a decent record in academics. If anyone could guide me for the next steps I should follow so as to get a job I would like doing. Particularly should involve statistics and probability, I am also well versed in Computer Science thanks to my degree. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With a background in CS and statistics the tech world will welcome you with open arms. All major internet players (google, facebook, amazon, netflix) make extensive use of A/B-testing and all other types of statistical analysis for market research.

I'd be looking for a role as a data scientist in a company with a big user base.

EDIT: I wouldn't bother going for internships but look for the full pay immediately.
Your skills are in demand and there is no reason to sell yourself below value and I can easily find job posts suitable for graduates in my area.

In terms of skills to acquire, you can look at typical requirements for junior data scientists and check whether you are checking all the boxes or there is skills you don't feel you have right now.
Make yourself at least familiar with these areas.

Comment: Before applying for jobs or internships as a data scientist, what all courses, projects or programmes (summer schools etc) should I consider doing? Because even a data scientist internship requires experience and are not particularly fresher friendly. Thankyou so much.

Comment: @hell i replied to this in an edit

Comment: Thanks a lot @Helena

Comment: Why would this be downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

As said, any forward looking company would be glad to have your skills.

The energy industry is one you could consider. I have similar interests and have done interesting work in modelling energy usage from distributed IoT devices right up to grid scale applications. There are many smaller companies innovating in this space right now.

Comment: Can you recommend any internships, programmes or courses I should do to get started, considering you have experience in this. It will be helpful for me to decide the direction I want to focus on. Thankyou so much for your time.